# Filenames in path

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to load all filenames from a folder in my project to a string array.

But I am not able to. Already tried it with the `DirectoryInfo`, but I am not able to load the wanted `Directory`.

Just to be sure. I do not want to copy all files to the `IsolatedStorage`. I just want to get the filenames.

Could anybody please provide me a solution to do it.

Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP7 application does not have any API to work with file system.

If you have files in project folder - you can mark them as Resources, and read them usin

`Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative));`

---

If files are marked as `Content` - you can not get the list of them. You can use only hardcoded names.

If files marked as Embedded Resources you can list them by this code:

```
var list = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. Ok if I declare the files in the folder as resource, i am not able to get all file names?

Comment: No, if they are content - you can not, but if they are resources - you can.

Comment: with `file.txt` set as resource you need to provide a different path. eg: "projectname;component/data/folder/file.txt"